# Passing data between Widgets without using Navigator?

Tags: flutter, state

I've some struggling with flutter.
I've two widget Details screen so in the first Details, I have a list and I want to send it to the second Screen without using navigator.

So if there is anyone who can help me I will be very thankful.

Details :

```
 List<String> _instructions = [];

class Details extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailsState createState() => new _DetailsState();
}

class _DetailsState extends State<Details> {
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                  child: OutlineButton(
                    highlightElevation: 21,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: StadiumBorder(),
                    textColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                    child: Text(
                      'ENVOYER',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                        width: 1),
                    onPressed: () {

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
}}
```

so what I want is that,when I press the button I will send my list to the next widget without using navigator.

Comment: Can you paste your code here? please edit your question with the code that you have tried with. So that it is so much easier to help you.

Comment: a code snippet might help describe the issue you are trying to solve. right now, im not sure we have enough information to be helpful

Comment: @PedroMassango i did it ,check my code .

Comment: How to you want to show the next widget? Maybe you want to use some architecture/state management pattern!

Comment: i want to display the content of the list , when i pressed the "ENVOYER" send button

Comment: you need to use constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have two pages, namely 'page1.dart' and 'page2.dart', both want to access the same list:

1. Create another dart file 'GlobalVariables.dart', inside this file, create a class gv.
2. Inside this class gv, create a static list by using:

```
static List <String> listAnyList = [];
```

3. import 'GlobalVariables.dart' in the 2 pages that need to access this list.
4. Now, in page1.dart and page2.dart, 
   you can use gv.listAnyList to access the 'Global List'.

Use 'Global Static Variables' if a variable is needed in many dart files, e.g. the 'User ID', then you can simply use gv.strUserID to access it in any pages you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the sharedpreferance which is the simple xml that belongs to the application. And this is how you can set it

```
Future<bool> setStringList(String key, List<String> value) =>
_setValue('StringList', key, value);

Future<bool> setStringList (
 String key, 
 List<String> value
)
```

For more info here is a [link](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
And you can get your List by

```
List<String> getStringList(String key) {
  List<Object> list = _preferenceCache[key];
    if (list != null && list is! List<String>) {
      list = list.cast<String>().toList();
      _preferenceCache[key] = list;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Also you can use [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Answer (score 0):

I think a more appropriate approach should be similar to how android fragments connect to each other using bloc pattern or master-details flow.
I created [an example repository](https://github.com/Yahhi/master_details_bloc) to show the complete concept. 
In short, the idea is to create a class with StreamController inside. Both widgets will have a reference to bloc instance. When the first widget wants to send data to the second it adds a new item to Stream. The second listen to the stream and updates its content accordingly.

Inside bloc:

```
  StreamController<String> _selectedItemController = new BehaviorSubject();

  Stream<String> get selectedItem => _selectedItemController.stream;

  void setSelected(String item) {
    _selectedItemController.add(item);
  }
```

First fragment:

```
class FragmentList extends StatelessWidget {
  final Bloc bloc;

  const FragmentList(
    this.bloc, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.selectedItem,
      initialData: "",
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> screenType) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              selected: bloc.items[index] == screenType.data,
              title: Text(bloc.items[index]),
              onTap: () {
                bloc.setSelected(bloc.items[index]);
              },
            );
          },
          itemCount: bloc.items.length,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The second fragment:

```
class FragmentDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final Bloc bloc;

  const FragmentDetails(
    this.bloc, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        initialData: "Nothing selected",
        stream: bloc.selectedItem,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> screenType) {
          final info = screenType.data;
          return Text(info);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```